# R-Subset of a data frame conditional to another data frame

Tags: r

Let I have two such data frames:

data frame1(df1):

```
col1 col2
x    x
x    x
x    y
y    y
```

data frame2(df2):

```
col1  col2
1.1   0.1
1.3   1.0
0.3   0.8
0.7   1.6
```

Desired output data frame(df) is:

```
col1  col2
0.7   0.8
NA    1.6
```

Namely, I want to produce a subset of df2, which mirrors df1="y". How can I do that using R? I will be very glad for any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Frank, I live format problem with your solution. The output is [$col1
character(0)

$col2
character(0)

$col3
character(0)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over columns:

```
lapply(1:ncol(df1),function(i) df2[[i]][df1[[i]]=="y"])
```

Or similarly:

```
mapply(function(a,b) a[b=="y"], df2,df1)
```

The result is a `list`, not a `data.frame`, but this seems best (since rows have no meaning).